# 'The breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols are loaded for this document'

Tags: dll, symbols, breakpoints

This problem began after the last-but-one VS2019 update but I can't specifically say (yet) that the update was the cause of the problem as I made some code changes after the update. This is a C++ add-on module (dll) for a mixed-mode (C++/dotNet) commercial product, so I don't have access to the original .exe code or .pdb files and I have to state that the product has never given trouble in itself in ten years of working with it. Importantly, it was all working until that update.

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2019 v4.8.09032
- Windows 11 fully patched
- Windows 11 optional updates (where required) fully patched

Current debug setup:

- Configuration Properties
- Debugging | Local Windows Debugger
- C/C++ | General | Program Database
- C/C++ | Code Generation | Multithreaded Debug Dll
- Linker | Debugging | Generate Debug Information
- Tools | Options | Debugging | disabled 'Enable Edit and Continue'

No pre- or post- build steps.

What I have tried:

- Rolled back the code changes
- Checked Configuration Manager (x64 Debug Active)
- Various combinations of the options available under C/C++ | Code Generation | Multithreaded Debug Dll and Linker | Debugging | Generate Debug Information
- Tools | Options | Debugging | checked and unchecked 'Enable Just My Code'
- Tools | Options | Debugging | checked and unchecked 'Require source files to exactly match the original version'
- Deleted the .vs folder and rebuilt it
- Deleted the entire Solution and copied back in an archived and known working Solution from four months ago (the Solution and the source files are in separate folders)

After each recompile I have manually deleted the .dll, .pdb, .lib and .exp files before copying in the new ones to ensure that no files are stale.

Additional information:

- The dll no longer shows up in Debug | Windows | Modules so I can't force a .pdb load (I'm guessing that fixing this might be the answer to the problem)
- The 'Dependencies' program says that there are no missing linkages

Interestingly (or not so!) I have found that I get the same error on every single project that I have tested in trying to debug the problem. This includes creating new projects and simply running older archived projects where the code has not been touched for months.

Updating to VS2022 is not currently an option but will have to follow once the current module is fully debugged in VS2019. The C++ version in use is ISO 17; I cannot upgrade the ISO version because of legacy C code that is no longer supported in ISO 20 and I cannot downgrade it because of some C++ updates in use that came with ISO 17.

Comment: It won't work as long as the DLL doesn't show up in the Modules list.  Most obvious setting that's relevant is Project > Properties > Debugging > "Debugger Type" = Mixed.  If the main startup project is C# then use Project > Properties > Debug > "Enable native code debugging" ticked.  Double-check that the test code actually tries to load the DLL (notification in the Output window) and that you see it back in the Modules list.

Comment: I've tried Mixed (dotnet Framework and dotNet Core) but to no avail. It was set to Auto. The project dll is not loading in the Output window but another dll of mine that the project dll makes a call to is being loaded. The Output window also states that the parent .exe is CLR 4.0.30319. Just to state the obvious for clarity, the project dll is being called by the parent .exe, otherwise I wouldn't see anything onscreen.

Comment: I still have this problem if anyone has any further suggestions. What I have done in the meantime is to uninstall both VS2019 and VS2022 and reinstall VS2019 only without any extensions. Unfortunately the problem still exists. It is doubly annoying in that dotNet debugging works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why the following worked, but it did.

- Under Project | Properties | Configuration Properties | Debugging set Command to the path to the executable (i.e. it's hard-coded and not $(TargetPath))
- Rebuild the project
- Copied the dll, pdb, exp and lib files to the folder where the executable expects to find them
- Hit the Local Windows Debugger green arrow instead of Debug | Attach To Process

The Debug | Window | Modules suddenly filled up with additional dlls - including mine - and the breakpoint was immediately hit.